# How to handle OpenSSL errors properly (BIO)

Tags: c++, openssl

Example code:

```
BIO* bio = BIO_new_file(file_name, "rb");
if (!bio)
{
    unsigned long err = ERR_peek_last_error()
    // err == 0
```

So BIO is NULL and error code is also 0. 
Which is the right way of the openssl error handling?

Answer (score 1):

In our case OpenSSL appeared to be built with "no-stdio" option. This resulted such behavior

Comment: Interesting. @MattCaswell was just talking about some unusual behavior from `BIO`'s, where a bio would not set an error code. Maybe this is a related problem.